# Upgrading Flutter causes this error: "The current Flutter version is 0.0.0-unknown"

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sdk

I upgraded my SDK tp 2.0.1 at my Windows OS but when i download project from github to my MACOS and i also downloaded SDK 2.0.1 macOS version i get this error. I can't switch channel to stable.

Flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel unknown, 0.0.0-unknown, on macOS 11.2 20D64 darwin-x64,
    locale tr-TR)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

I have to work at 2.0.1 Flutter SDK version. Help please.

Comment: Flutter relies on Git tags to determine its version.  If it can't find any tags, it'll report 0.0.0.  It sounds like you've broken your SDK checkout (did you squash it?).

Comment: yes i copy 2.0.1 files and pasted it over to 1.14.5 how can i fix this

Comment: Reinstall the Flutter 2.0.2 SDK from scratch, either by [cloning the GitHub project](https://github.com/flutter/flutter) or by [downloading and extracting the `.zip` file](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos).  If you do copy the SDK files from one location to another, you need to be sure to copy the hidden `.git` folder so that you end up with a working Git repository.

Comment: i already downloaded flutter 2.0.1 for macOS and change the files with that. Didn't work

Comment: What do you mean by "change the files with that"?

Comment: i changed old 1.14.5 SDK with 2.0.1 stable SDK

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230118/discussion-between-jamesdlin-and-ergun-yunus-cengiz).